# Why am I getting the error: argument of length 0

Tags: r, shiny, syntax-error

While identifying categorical from qualitative variable I wrote the following code and it works all fine!

```
E=read.csv(file = "B.csv",header = TRUE, row.names = 1,sep = ";")

for(i in c(1:ncol(E))){
  if((class(E[,i])=="integer") && length(unique(E[,i]))<=5){E[,i]<-factor(E[,i])}
}
x=sapply(E,class)
x=(x=="numeric")
df=E[,x]
if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)
names(df)
```

It gets me all the qualitative variables and identify the numeric variable where levels length is less than 5 as categorical one! 
Despite this, while I'm putting my code to a shiny app I get the error

```
argument of length 0
```

The code at the app is:

```
 ui = fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("One-way ANOVA",
             numericInput("n","n", value=5,min=3, step=1),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Upload your  CSV File'),
                 htmlOutput("varselectOne"),
                 htmlOutput("factorVar") ),
               mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("ANOVA Table", dataTableOutput("anova1")
                   )))))))


server <- function(input, output) {

  myData1 <- reactive({
    # validate(
    #   need(input$myData1 != "", "")
    # )

    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,row.names=1)
    data
  })

  ## for one factor

  output$varselectOne <- renderUI({

    for(i in c(1:ncol(myData1()))){
      if((class(myData1()[,i])=="integer") && length(unique(myData1()[,i]))<=input$n){myData1()[,i]<-factor(myData1()[,i])}
    }
    x=sapply(myData1(),class)
    x=(x=="numeric")
    df=myData1()[,x]

    if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)

    # Variable selection: 

    selectInput(inputId = "varsOne", label = "Variables to use:", choices=names(df), selected=names(df), multiple =TRUE)     
  })





}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I want is that quantitative variables get inserted into the selectInput field. Any help?

The data is

```
;Var;Lo;ES;Acidity;K232;K270;IP;OS;C 14:0;C 16:0;C 16:1;C 17:0;C 17:1;C 18:0;C 18:1;C 18:2;C 18:3;C 20:0;C 20:1;total;LLL;LnLO;LnLP;LLO;LnOO;PLL;LOO;LOP;PLP;OOO;POP;POO;AOL;SOO;SOP;Chlorophyll;b carotène;polyphenols ;Ethyl acetate;2- Methyl butanal;3- Methyl butanal;1-Penten-3-one;3-Hexanone;Hexanal;3-Pentanol;Trans-2-pentenal;1-Penten-3-ol;Cis-3-hexenal;Trans-2-hexenal;1-Pentanol;Hexyl acetate;Cis-3-hexenyl acetate;Cis-2-pentenol;6-Methyl-5-hepten-2-one;1-Hexanol;Trans-3-hexenol;Cis-3-hexenol;Trans-2-hexenol;Acetic acid;Butyric acid;H-   Tyr      ;Tyr ;DFOA;DFLA;Ac-Pin;Pin;EAA;OA;LA;total phenols (HPLC)
P1;chetoui;beja;1;0.93;1.49;0.2;9.2;16.51;0.01;13.5;0.57;0.07;0.08;2.57;67.04;18.56;1.16;0.02;0.39;103.95;0.72;0.45;0.1;7.87;2.63;0.38;22.14;8.8;0.7;33.47;15.84;1.77;0.37;3.95;0.8;5.05;4.1;491.6;2.72;0.29;0.11;0.08;0.1;15.27;1.35;1.55;3.77;22.68;133.13;0.36;9.92;7.14;2.37;0.5;10.03;0.78;121.11;14.12;0.05;0.08;1.91;4.15;10.33;40.52;1.21;5.5;2.92;30.65;2.35;99.53
P2;chetoui;beja;1;0.36;1.24;0.2;8.2;16.81;0.01;13.39;0.18;0.05;0.07;1.23;69.23;18.63;0.91;0.02;0.28;104;0.69;0.43;0.15;7.81;2.57;0.42;22.21;8.84;0.71;33.87;15.6;2.01;0.38;4.14;1.01;5.88;6.161;457.04;2.52;0.34;0.12;0.09;0.22;15.2;1.32;1.52;3.67;22.61;133.19;0.35;9.89;7.18;2.34;0.51;10.17;0.75;121.21;14.29;0.05;0.02;1.92;4.05;10.45;40.63;1.25;5.55;2.95;31.042;2.17;100.01
P3;chetoui;beja;1;0.84;1.87;0.21;8.6;16.73;0.01;13.31;0.45;0.06;0.08;2.54;69.29;17.03;0.84;0.02;0.37;104;0.72;0.42;0.12;7.82;2.61;0.43;21.22;8.83;0.72;33.85;15.52;1.92;0.39;4.05;0.95;5.92;6.241;482.12;2.72;0.25;0.08;1.12;0.42;15.01;1.3;1.44;3.93;22.51;133.07;0.39;9.87;7.16;2.31;0.52;10.1;0.76;121.29;14.21;0.06;0.01;1.93;4.12;10.6;40.71;1.26;5.54;2.96;30.43;2.26;99.81
P4;chetoui;beja;2;0.3;1.96;0.22;10.4;16.95;0.01;13.64;0.4;0.06;0.07;2.9;70.57;15.48;0.72;0.51;0.45;104.81;0.39;0.37;0.08;5.92;2.16;0.46;20.65;8.01;0.61;36.29;17.28;1.92;0.54;4.53;0.79;5.83;6.122;659.75;2.23;0;0.4;1.82;0.83;8.37;0.17;0.34;3.63;18.73;139.68;0.07;3.33;7.96;2.87;0.14;9.51;0.24;115.12;16.78;0.26;0.21;0.28;0.53;10.25;10.05;0.24;2.54;0.32;97.84;0.09;122.15
P5;chetoui;beja;2;0.27;1.43;0.19;10.8;15.26;0.01;13.05;0.14;0.05;0.06;1.96;72.44;14.98;0.58;0.37;0.34;103.99;0.36;0.35;0.12;5.86;2.1;0.42;20.74;7.97;0.63;36.6;17;2.16;0.53;4.69;1.01;5.74;5.135;639.63;2.93;0;0.44;1.65;0.89;8.29;0.18;0.35;3.54;18.81;137.89;0.06;3.31;7.99;2.95;0.14;9.68;0.23;115.11;16.6;0.31;0.22;0.25;0.55;10.22;10.21;0.25;2.56;0.33;98.11;0.13;122.61
P6;chetoui;beja;2;0.28;1.5;0.2;10.1;15.09;0.01;13.84;0.39;0.05;0.08;2.5;71.44;14.42;0.51;0.4;0.37;104;0.37;0.34;0.1;5.81;2.13;0.41;20.56;7.96;0.62;36.62;17.04;2.05;0.52;4.6;0.95;5.42;5.2;640.39;2.58;0;0.46;1.77;0.95;8.21;0.16;0.32;3.94;18.88;137.23;0.07;3.27;7.94;2.9;0.15;9.61;0.22;116.03;16.66;0.32;0.24;0.26;0.57;10.16;10.1;0.26;2.51;0.35;98.38;0.11;122.7
P7;chetoui;beja;3;0.29;1.15;0.19;12.6;14.67;0.01;12.03;0.45;0.06;0.07;2.79;69.54;15.32;0.69;0.46;0.4;101.83;0.39;0.37;0.09;5.69;2.13;0.32;20.37;8.28;0.65;35.79;17.8;2;0.53;4.62;0.97;6.57;5.16;424.08;2.22;0.77;1.96;1.15;0.76;7.59;0.55;0.05;3.52;11.03;70.44;0.26;1.79;7.27;2.85;0.35;6.73;0.44;115.35;13.05;0.26;0;0.7;1.04;10.37;21;3.26;9.23;4.45;50.48;5.36;105.89
P8;chetoui;beja;3;0.25;1.54;0.19;12.4;14.43;0.01;12.71;0.09;0.04;0.07;1.04;72.3;15.48;0.61;0.33;0.33;103;0.42;0.35;0.14;5.61;1.97;0.28;20.42;8.33;0.63;36.19;17.6;2.24;0.54;4.81;1.18;6.59;5.3;425.68;2.5;0.82;1.99;1.21;0.65;7.62;0.55;0.05;3.43;11.17;71.28;0.22;1.76;7.3;2.87;0.36;6.81;0.42;115.38;13.61;0.31;0;0.72;1.12;10.33;20.74;3.28;9.11;4.44;50.67;5.41;105.82
P9;chetoui;beja;3;0.26;1.37;0.18;12.3;14.51;0.01;10.7;0.47;0.06;0.08;2.63;70.29;14.46;0.53;0.41;0.37;100;0.43;0.34;0.12;5.6;2;0.27;20.43;8.35;0.64;36.24;17.65;2.15;0.52;4.71;1.05;6.33;5.42;424.19;2.8;0.75;2.04;1.26;0.66;7.84;0.52;0.04;3.47;11.1;71.41;0.24;1.72;7.12;2.88;0.37;6.88;0.43;115.36;13.69;0.22;0;0.73;1.1;10.41;20.15;3.29;9.25;4.31;51.01;5.88;106.13
P10;arbequina; morneg;4;0.47;1.27;0.25;12.5;9.98;0.02;15.9;1.94;0.09;0.19;1.77;66.15;12.71;0.58;0.37;0.28;100;0.19;0.33;0.08;4.16;2.02;0.75;17.17;11.72;1.19;30.88;23.37;4.04;0.36;2.93;0.82;5.74;3.81;160.03;3.29;1.4;0.7;0.8;0.59;35.06;1.12;0.55;3.67;24.7;149.45;0.22;4.08;2.2;8.16;0.17;11.75;0.9;29.92;6.98;0.84;0.34;0.25;0.34;9.97;10.23;0.43;7.89;0.75;10.63;0.31;40.8
P11;arbequina; morneg;4;0.48;1.3;0.19;10.2;9.66;0.02;16.87;1.81;0.1;0.18;1.18;64.97;13.57;0.58;0.39;0.31;99.99;0.17;0.31;0.1;4.13;2.01;0.71;17.26;11.71;1.2;31.25;23.15;4.28;0.37;2.97;0.83;5.7;3.77;161.14;3.52;1.54;0.89;0.88;0.6;35.74;1.24;0.52;2.85;21.52;147.85;0.25;4.85;2.75;8.25;0.19;11.79;0.95;30.11;6.71;0.89;0.35;0.22;0.32;10.14;10.42;0.45;7.66;0.77;10.27;0.42;40.67
P12;arbequina; morneg;4;0.47;1.61;0.22;11.6;9.73;0.02;16.04;1.93;0.09;0.18;1.46;66.77;12.16;0.54;0.46;0.35;100;0.16;0.3;0.09;4.15;2;0.7;17.11;11.7;1.21;31.3;23.12;2.15;0.38;2.95;0.84;5.65;3.89;160.45;3.11;1.62;0.75;0.77;0.58;35.44;1.32;0.44;2.96;22.85;148.52;0.31;4.25;2.85;8.74;0.21;11.93;0.97;30.85;6.93;0.91;0.48;0.24;0.33;10.22;10.31;0.44;7.8;0.76;11.2;0.47;41.77
P13;arbequina; morneg;2;0.2;1.43;0.07;9.4;7.35;0.01;14.63;1.82;0.07;0.14;2.12;65.12;14.94;0.98;0;0.15;99.99;0.25;0.4;0.11;4.77;2.51;0.57;17.65;12.93;1.37;27.95;23.16;4.43;0.32;2.82;0.78;6.61;4.18;188.41;1.03;1.15;1.05;0.26;0.33;18.05;0.88;0.65;3.41;15.65;136.49;0.17;3.17;4.54;7.21;0.15;4.65;0.47;38.28;4.6;0.09;0.11;0.2;1.82;10.03;10.65;0.62;1.29;3.55;19.25;0.54;47.94
P14;arbequina; morneg;2;0.28;2.11;0.12;7.6;7.29;0.02;14.31;1.61;0.07;0.1;2.33;66.18;14.14;1.03;0;0.17;99.97;0.28;0.39;0.09;4.8;2.5;0.53;17.64;12.92;1.39;28.3;22.95;4.68;0.33;2.86;0.79;6.49;4.2;187.16;0.9;1.21;1.11;0.27;0.35;18.24;0.89;0.67;3.39;15.57;137.51;0.2;3.14;4.57;7.24;0.16;4.65;0.45;38.36;4.57;0.07;0.1;0.21;1.85;10.16;10.78;0.66;1.31;3.41;19.4;0.49;48.27
P15;arbequina; morneg;2;0.25;1.72;0.1;8.3;7.3;0.02;15.24;2.1;0.06;0.094;1.94;64.22;15.33;0.757;0;0.21;99.98;0.23;0.38;0.1;4.76;2.52;0.52;17.63;12.91;1.38;28.35;22.9;4.5;0.35;2.8;0.8;6.72;4.25;187.62;0.96;1.04;1.07;0.27;0.32;18.29;0.87;0.53;3.35;15.47;137.98;0.22;3.21;4.51;7.25;0.16;4.64;0.44;38.35;4.64;0.12;0.09;0.23;1.88;10.38;10.79;0.67;1.35;3.42;19.64;0.53;48.89
P16;arbequina; morneg;3;0.17;1.81;0.11;11.6;7.11;0.02;13.57;1.56;0.09;0.17;1.93;67.63;13.42;0.61;0.63;0.35;99.97;0.27;0.3;0.04;4.59;1.95;0.64;17.38;11.06;1.12;31.42;22.27;4.04;0.45;3.02;0.95;6.14;3.95;199.17;1.22;0.2;0.31;0.23;0.68;19.18;0.34;0.19;5.9;13.17;73.3;0.22;4.2;7.17;3.4;0.17;6.4;1.31;36.39;5.78;0.11;0.12;0.2;1.06;10.15;10.05;0.17;8.1;0.77;23.6;0.28;54.38
P17;arbequina; morneg;3;0.22;1.37;0.11;11.2;7.48;0.02;13.58;0.96;0.07;0.17;0.7;69.65;13.68;0.33;0.56;0.27;100;0.24;0.31;0.06;4.62;1.94;0.62;17.36;11.04;1.15;32.02;22.05;3.81;0.46;3.06;0.96;6.22;3.9;196.81;1.25;0.24;0.35;0.27;0.71;19.22;0.33;0.22;5.96;13.22;72.35;0.24;4.24;7.1;3.42;0.18;6.41;1.3;36.47;5.71;0.15;0.14;0.21;1.11;10.26;10.23;0.18;8.15;0.75;23.41;0.31;54.61
P18;arbequina; morneg;3;0.19;1.09;0.09;11.5;7.24;0.02;14.06;1.61;0.09;0.25;1.81;68.27;12.11;0.72;0.71;0.34;100;0.25;0.32;0.05;4.58;1.96;0.61;17.67;11.05;1.14;30.82;22;3.95;0.47;3.08;0.97;6.09;3.86;198.72;1.21;0.26;0.36;0.28;0.75;19.07;0.33;0.18;5.82;13.09;73.89;0.19;4.25;7.12;3.45;0.16;6.41;1.32;36.31;5.8;0.16;0.15;0.22;1.12;10.19;10.05;0.19;8.11;0.79;23.5;0.37;54.54
P19;chemlali;chaal;4;0.18;1.67;0.1;10.2;6.25;0.01;15.8;2.16;0.04;0.08;2.32;60.37;17.8;0.61;0.61;0.21;99.99;0.5;0.46;0.14;6.5;3.87;0.61;18.41;15.06;2.11;21.92;21.6;4.54;0.17;3.04;1.07;6.95;4.99;187.23;2.85;0.41;0.29;0;0.62;18.13;3.22;0;6.21;28.38;83.24;0.44;9.92;1.74;5.38;0.35;14.92;0.88;17.53;8.94;0.44;0;0.14;0.86;11.32;10;0.03;0.23;0.07;40.42;0.16;63.25
P20;chemlali;chaal;4;0.2;1.55;0.1;12.2;7.17;0.01;16.39;1.95;0.04;0.07;1.69;61.55;17.09;0.51;0.51;0.22;100.02;0.53;0.44;0.12;6.53;3.89;0.57;18.4;15.04;2.1;21.94;21.4;4.5;0.26;3.08;1.08;6.85;4.84;185.84;2.97;0.45;0.29;0;0.63;18.22;3.25;0;6.28;28.47;84.54;0.47;9.96;1.79;5.39;0.34;14.93;0.9;17.43;8.91;0.49;0;0.13;0.85;11.48;9.96;0.04;0.25;0.08;39.97;0.15;62.91
P21;chemlali;chaal;4;0.2;1.31;0.09;11.9;7.2;0.01;15.15;2.03;0.03;0.09;2.72;60.56;18.04;0.52;0.54;0.31;100;0.54;0.45;0.13;6.54;3.88;0.56;18.42;15.05;2.12;21.96;21.38;4.53;0.2;3.06;1.09;6.15;4.04;186.15;2.91;0.42;0.31;0;0.65;18.27;3.27;0;6.25;27.99;84.98;0.49;9.87;1.78;5.24;0.34;14.91;0.91;17.59;9;0.51;0;0.12;0.82;11.43;10.22;0.03;0.27;0.08;40.3;0.26;63.53
P22;chemlali;chaal;2;0.33;1.27;0.12;9.2;7.71;0.01;15.21;1.91;0.05;0.08;2.45;61.83;17.08;0.65;0.51;0.24;100;0.42;0.44;0.15;5.9;3.3;0.98;18.2;14.51;2;22.69;21.91;4.9;0.18;3.24;1.18;4.81;4.109;282.65;0.98;1.52;1;0.21;1.17;29.5;2.69;0.82;2.24;25.96;63.63;0.32;9.18;2.41;10.14;1.28;14.25;0.9;65.02;1.61;0.63;0;2.46;2.15;10.68;20.2;0.13;4.16;1.43;50.38;1.19;92.78
P23;chemlali;chaal;2;0.28;1.51;0.15;9.9;6.35;0.01;15.33;1.96;0.06;0.17;1.23;63.23;16.53;0.59;0.55;0.32;99.99;0.45;0.42;0.17;5.93;3.28;0.94;18.21;14.5;2.02;22.72;21.62;4.95;0.28;3.2;1.19;4.82;4.117;253.92;0.96;1.62;1.02;0.24;1.2;29.78;2.74;0.88;2.25;25.47;63.89;0.35;9.21;2.41;10.17;1.29;14.25;0.92;65.09;16.72;0.69;0;2.55;2.07;10.77;20.34;0.12;4.15;1.45;50.18;1.25;92.88
P24;chemlali;chaal;2;0.29;1.94;0.13;9.5;6.4;0.01;14.13;2.16;0.05;0.08;2.02;62.17;17.72;0.6;0.62;0.44;100;0.45;0.41;0.16;5.87;3.29;0.95;18.22;14.52;2.01;22.71;21.58;4.92;0.2;3.22;1.2;4.88;4.165;271.92;0.96;1.59;1.09;0.19;1.14;29.42;2.77;0.85;2.24;25.59;62.96;0.36;9.22;2.42;10.16;1.31;14.25;0.88;65.14;16.87;0.61;0;2.56;2.09;10.77;19.82;0.11;4.12;1.42;50.31;1.25;92.45
P25;chemlali;chaal;3;0.34;1.39;0.11;12.8;6.71;0.01;15.85;2.01;0.04;0.09;2.35;60.13;18.06;0.61;0.44;0.21;99.8;0.51;0.45;0.17;6.58;3.48;0.87;18.74;15.16;1.86;21.97;21.72;4.83;0.2;2.61;0.85;2.26;2.349;285.29;1;1.59;1.07;1.7;1.27;34.05;2.93;0.99;3.7;26.3;62.42;0.39;9.98;2.71;10.15;1.53;14.25;1.41;72.29;87.36;0.75;0.13;0.16;0.65;10;10.25;0.11;2.73;0.63;45.27;0.14;69.94
P26;chemlali;chaal;3;0.33;1.86;0.11;11.6;6.84;0.01;15.95;0.52;0.06;0.14;2.86;62.14;16.83;1.13;0.04;0.32;100;0.55;0.46;0.15;6.55;3.45;0.83;18.73;15.17;1.83;21.99;21.52;4.87;0.3;2.65;0.86;2.515;2.146;286.05;0.98;1.69;1.09;1.53;1.29;34.33;2.93;1.07;3.7;25.81;62.68;0.42;10.01;2.71;10.21;1.55;14.25;1.44;72.29;88.7;0.75;0.11;0.15;0.61;9.93;10.19;0.12;2.75;0.62;45.56;0.14;70.07
P27;chemlali;chaal;3;0.33;1.69;0.1;11.9;6.8;0.01;16.94;0.54;0.07;0.11;2.1;59.62;19.2;0.91;0.03;0.45;99.99;0.54;0.47;0.16;6.54;3.44;0.82;18.72;15.18;1.84;22;21.48;4.9;0.25;2.62;0.84;2.597;2.748;285.46;0.99;1.66;1.16;1.68;1.23;33.97;2.95;1.02;3.69;25.93;61.75;0.43;10.02;2.72;10.22;1.58;14.25;1.41;72.32;87.76;0.68;0.15;0.17;0.66;10.64;10.37;0.1;2.65;0.66;45.49;0.26;71
```

Comment: Just Check `myData1()` it's probably null. What you get is the difference between using `for (i in seq_along(df))` and `for (i in c(1:ncol(df)))` when `df` is `NULL`. Also, please provides a minimal reproducible example with a dataset in such way we can copy and paste to RStudio.

Comment: Here you are I've updated the code to a reproducible minimal code ! but still didnt get what u mentioned there!!

Comment: Well even if I add sep=";" it can't solve my problem really

Comment: In fact if I delete the for loop inside output$varselectOne it will give the result but with no controle if a numeric column is qualitative or quantitative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was

> Error in myData1()[, i] <- factor(myData1()[, i]) : 
>     invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

which is generated as `myData1()` is not a normal data frame but a reactive environment. You can uncomment `browser()` to check the for loop step by step. I change the sep in `read.csv` from default to `';'`.

```
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("One-way ANOVA",
               numericInput("n","n", value=5,min=3, step=1),
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   fileInput('file1', 'Upload your  CSV File'),
                   htmlOutput("varselectOne"),
                   htmlOutput("factorVar") ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel("ANOVA Table", dataTableOutput("anova1")
                     )))))))


  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    myData1 <- reactive({
      # validate(
      #   need(input$myData1 != "", "")
      # )

      inFile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
      data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,row.names=1, sep=";")
      data
    })

    #observe(print(myData1()))

    ## for one factor

    output$varselectOne <- renderUI({
      #browser()
      req(myData1())

      df_init <- myData1() 
      #for(i in seq_along(df_init)) #Better than below
      for(i in c(1:ncol(df_init))){
        if((class(df_init[,i])=="integer") && length(unique(df_init[,i]))<=input$n){df_init[,i]<-factor(df_init[,i])}
      }
      x=sapply(df_init,class)
      x=(x=="numeric")
      df=df_init[,x]

      if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)

      # Variable selection:

      selectInput(inputId = "varsOne", label = "Variables to use:", choices=names(df), selected=names(df), multiple =TRUE)
    })





  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works correctly! can u explain how can I detect similar problems? what techniques do you use? I'm was frustrated with this one!

Comment: In the server side, you can uncomment `observe(print(myData1()))` to check if the data has been read correctly to shiny server. If you uncomment `browser()`, when you run the App you will be in the Debugger mode which you can check each step in the code using Next which will be visible once you are in the Debugger Mode

Comment: Check [here for R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) and [here for Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html) for more details about Debugging.